# Create a table with range in column in sql

Tags: sql

I need to create a table like this..

```
claim amount      court fee
exceed 300          15
301-500             30
501-1000            55
```

and so on..

I tried it my claim amount was nvarchar and court fee was float i get an error  converting nvarchar to numeric.

When I try this query on `select * from table where claim amount <=250` it displays all the rows. I am confused with what datatype should be used for claim amount and how can I be specific when retreiving the query like <=275...

Comment: I agree with @astader, a start and end value would be best. If you are adamant you want your database like so, then you would have to select everything and then use php and loop through the data exploding the field by the "-" and then testing the value with an if statement or something.

Comment: table structure is wrong , split column as posted below in answer . Also shouldn't exceed 300 be less than 300 ?

Comment: Which DBMS yre you using? Postgres offers range types which are exactly meant for that (and are very efficient as well)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should split this up into 2 columns making them both type `int`.

MinClaimAmount and MaxClaimAmount (otherwise you'll have to do string splitting and other nonsense).

```
MinClaimAmount  MaxClaimAmount     courtFee
0                  300                15
301                500                30
501                1000               55
```

Then, your SQL would be (if you wanted a specific row)

```
select * from  table where MinClaimAmount <= 275 AND MaxClaimAmount >= 275
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/22131)

Comment: the second query returns all rows

Comment: I am sorry to say that I tried your query but its not working.

Comment: I tried to delete the table and have created and now its works perfectly fine Ignore previous comment...

Comment: I am trying to inner join with other table and I have Payments in  the  new table can you please check this query                 `select * from [ICPS].[dbo].[Courtfees] inner join [ICPS].[dbo].[vPCN_Payments] as a on
a.Payments <= [ICPS].[dbo].[Courtfees]. [Min ClaimAmount] and
a.Payments >= [ICPS].[dbo].[Courtfees].[Max Claim Amount]`

Comment: I am sorry I thought to mark both answers as correct  as i dont know that marking one answer unticks the other answer. I am really sorry

Comment: @preethi Your new query is somewhat back wards compared to the question here... Any way I suggest you delete this new question in your comments and ask a brand new question. Provide as much detail as you can (as you have in this question). This is a Q&A site, each question should be on it's own page, it's not a forum where questions continues etc... (well, not always)

Answer (score 3):

I would create a table with a start and end value, with the start value null for opening entry and end value null for the closing value.

Something like

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(
    ID INT IDENTITY (1,1),
    StartValue FLOAT,
    EndValue FLOAT,
    FeeValue FLOAT
)

INSERT INTO @Table SELECT null,300,15
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 301,500,30
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 501,1000,50
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 1001,null,100

DECLARE @LookupValue FLOAT = 275

SELECT  *
FROm    @Table
WHERE   ISNULL(StartValue, @LookupValue) <= @LookupValue
AND     ISNULL(EndValue, @LookupValue) >= @LookupValue
```

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/22106)

Comment: I ma very much new to this concept astander, I am working on your query. Thanks

Comment: I tried it on sql fiddle  it works perfectly but when i run the query on sql server it  gives me error.......................... Cannot assign a default value to a local variable.
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 24
Must declare the variable '@LookupValue'.

Comment: SELECT  *
FROm    @courtfee where feevalue = 75 give me error Must declare the variable '@courtfee' please help.....

Comment: SELECT  *
FROm    [Court Fees] where StartValue > 70 and EndValue < 300
 returns empty rows